# collapse and (lambda s: " ".join(s.split())) or (lambda s: s)

Tags: python, lambda

I'm new to python.When I　search the **lambda** in the internet .
I found this statement in [lambda_functions](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html).

```
processFunc = collapse and (lambda s: " ".join(s.split())) or (lambda s: s)
```

It's very werid for me.Why he don't write it like this?

```
processFunc = collapse and " ".join(s.split()) or s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `processFunc` must be a *function*, not the *result* of calling a function.

In fact the line:

```
processFunc = collapse and " ".join(s.split()) or s
```

Will raise a `NameError` because `s` is not defined. If `s` was defined then, depending on what `collapse` is it might evaluate to to the *string* `" ".join(s.split())` or to the `s`.

While the line:

```
processFunc = collapse and (lambda s: " ".join(s.split())) or (lambda s: s)
```

Will evaluate to the *function* `(lambda s: " ".join(s.split()))` if `collapse` is true, or to the function `(lambda s: s)` otherwise.

Note that writing `A and B or C` is somewhat equivalent to writing `B if A else C`, although they are *not* 100% equivalent, because in the `if` version only `A`s boolean value is important to determining the result of the expression, while in the other code if `A` is true and `B` is false the result is `C`.

You should really re-write that line as:

```
processFunc = (lambda s: " ".join(s.split())) if collapse else (lambda s: s)
```

Although *in this specific case* the `and`+`or` form is equivalent because all `lambda`s are true.

And you might even replace the `lambda`s with real functions to enhance readability:

```
def identity(x):
    return x

def normalize_spaces(s):
    return ' '.join(s.split())

processFunc = normalize_spaces if collapse else identity
```

Answer (score 1):

In other form, it is:

```
processFunc =  (lambda s: " ".join(s.split())) if collapse else (lambda s: s)
```

(BTW, this form - by my measurements - is usually more efficient)

**EDIT:**

I've seen a lot of explanation what it does - but here's the rationale behind the idea.
Essentially, when *collapse* is a global variable set once (command line or configuration), and the following function

```
def processFunc(s):
    return " ".join(s.split()) if collapse else s
```

is called zillion times, checking condition on each calls adds a processing overhead - which may be considerable. Splitting functionality into 2 functions, evaluating condition **once** and assigning references to functions makes your code more performance-efficient

Comment: @migilson, and I totally agree with you! I used this form a couple of times with string assignments - and I've changed it to __if .. else__ after timing it

Answer (score 0):

Using a function defers evaluation of the expression until some later point.  `" ".join(s.split())` is a string.  `(lambda s: " ".join(s.split()))` is a function which, when called, will return a string.  If you need a function (i.e., if that object is something you're going to try to call later), you need the function, not its result.

In this case, at the time you define `processFunc` there might not even be any `s` in scope.  The function is created, but it splits/joins the string you pass it later.  To do `" ".join(s.split())` directly, you would need to have `s` here right now.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very compact way of assigning one of two **functions** to `processFunc`. The point of the `lambda`s here is not to do anything to any strings right at the moment, but rather to set up a function which can be called later to either collapse or not collapse whitespace.

If `collapse` is true then it assigns the function `lambda s: " ".join(s.split())`, which makes `processFunc` a function that collapses whitespace. If `collapse` is false then it assigns a no-op function `(lambda s: s)`, in which case `processFunc` simply returns its input unchanged.

You could equivalently, and perhaps more clearly, write the line as:

```
def collapseWhitespace(s):
    return " ".join(s.split())

def doNothing(s):
    return s

if collapse:
    processFunc = collapseWhitespace
else:
    processFunc = doNothing
```